# Postfix: reject_sender_login_mismatch not working

Tags: postfix, sasl

I want to use the following configuration for Postfix:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks reject_sender_login_mismatch permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination, check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf
smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/controlled_envelope_senders
```

`controlled_envelope_senders` contains a single entry for my SASL user:

```
xyz@example.com username@example.com
```

This setup mostly works fine, but there are two issues.

1. Postfix accepts message from other addresses (e.g. abc@example.com or def@otherdomain.org) for user@example.com:

```
Feb  6 08:28:21 eden postfix/submission/smtpd[568746]: connect from cable-87-79-207-4.nc.de[87.79.207.4]
Feb  6 08:28:21 eden postfix/submission/smtpd[568746]: F0F207F941: client=cable-87-79-207-4.nc.de[87.79.207.4], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=user@example.com
Feb  6 08:28:22 eden postfix/cleanup[568753]: F0F207F941: message-id=<Yf+GpT7tRUKyS6b5@example.com>
Feb  6 08:28:22 eden postfix/qmgr[568743]: F0F207F941: from=<abc@example.com>, size=770, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
```

2. For external messages sent to one of my `virtual_alias_domains`, there is a warning in mail.log:

```
Feb  6 08:45:35 eden postfix/smtpd[568806]: warning: restriction `reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch' ignored: no SASL support
```

I did not specify `reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch`, and these messages are not sent by authenticated senders – so what does this warning refer to?

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: The parameters for submission in `/etc/postfix/master.cf` did not specify `reject_sender_login_mismatch` (overwriting the setting in main.cf), and since sasl was not for smtpd in main.cf, so the reject directive made no sense there.